# Unable to resolve memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

i am unable to resolve a memory-leak in my little program. Some of the code was originally created in Java, so i was "converting" it to c++ (some of those things might seem strange, so if you have a better solution, please let me know - im quite new to OOP in C++).
My intention is to create a random heightmap generator.
There are 2 memory leaks (found with Visual Leak Detector):

The first one gets triggered here:

```
-> Mountain* mount = new Mountain(size, Utils::powerOf2Log2(size) - 6, 0.5f, seed);
   ChannelClass* height = mount->toChannel();
```

Because of this in the "Mountain" class constructor:

```
channel = new ChannelClass(size, size);
```

I was trying to use a shutdown method like so:

```
mount->ShutDown();
delete mount;
mount = 0;
```

With Shutdown() defined as such:

```
if(channel){
    channel->ShutDown();
    delete channel;
    channel = 0;
}
```

The ShutDown() method of "ChannelClass" is deleting an float array. My initial thought was that maybe "ChannelClass* height = mount->toChannel()" is causing problems there.

If you need more code please let me know! Thanks in advance for any one willing to help!

Comment: And if you do, you store them in the `scoped_ptr`. So you don't actually use `*`.

Comment: So what should i use instead? An example would be really nice :)

Comment: Does Mountain inherit from another class?  If so does that class have a virtual destructor?

Comment: Didn't you forget to delete the array with `delete[]`?

Comment: We may need more code. However, the shutdown method may be a bit overkill. `delete` will unallocate the memory to the pointer itself. Reassigning it to 0 does nothing of use just for memory allocation. Are you sure you delete all heap-allocated memory? The tool `valgrind` is great for teasing out memory leaks.

Comment: Mountain does not inherit from another class.

Comment: And by the way, which object gets leaked?

Comment: Just say `Mountain mount(size, Utils::powerOf2Log2(size) - 6, 0.5f, seed);`, and so forth.

Comment: Are you using the delete[] instead of delete for the array as Vlad suggested?

Comment: If mount isn't polymorphic and isn't supposed to live past the end of the function you should declare it as `Mountain mount(size, Utils::powerOf2Log2(size) - 6, 0.5f, seed);`. Otherwise you should use a smart pointer like std::shared_ptr like this `auto mount = std::make_shared<Mountain>(size, Utils::powerOf2Log2(size) - 6, 0.5f, seed);`. You should almost never use a raw pointer in C++.

Comment: Yes. I am using delete[] for the array.

Comment: I will try what Kerrek SB and Dirk were suggesting. Thanks so far!

Comment: @KerrekSB That's an overly narrowed view! Using `new` and `delete` in C++ is perfectly OK as long you know what you're doing. Otherwise you should really explain which of the smart pointer classes should be used instead (and even these will require an instance created with `new` to be initialized)

Comment: @KerrekSB Also creating an instance on the stack might not be appropriate for all situations ...

Comment: @g-makulik: If you know what you're doing, you have a maker function a la `make_unique`!

Comment: Also, you don't often need old-style arrays in C++. If the size is known at compile time, use `std::array` otherwise use `std::vector`. Let the library take care of the memory management wherever possible, and your life will become much easier.

Comment: All the comments bring valid general suggestions, but @puelo, you need to show more code - what you have right does not show a memory leak.

Comment: @KerrekSB `make_unique` is c++11 specific, isn't it? The question isn't explicitly c++11 oriented, and even if you use your RYO `make_unique` factory method you'll end up using `new` somewhere in the code. So saying 'you don't use `new` in C++` is an overly narrowed view, period!

Comment: This question is not tagged C++11.  As such, it's appropriate to assume that support for C++11 stl classes is not present.  It's like telling someone using Java 5 that they should be using a foreach loop.

Comment: @g-makulik: You do understand that generalizations are meant to apply *in general*, right? If you're able to tell that there may be cases where `new` is useful, then you should also be able to tell that his comment isn't directed to you.

Comment: @GManNickG So following your logic about generalizations one can say that '`new` **shouldn't** be used in C++' but of course not 'In C++, you don't use new.' That's simply not correct ...

Comment: @g-makulik: You're still missing the point. Not every sentence is said with the intent of being read as a formal statement. Look at the sentence and don't try to assign it a truth value, it's okay. :) It's a just a command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so without more code this is going to be pretty general.  These are guidelines (not rules) with the most preferred first.

First, a quick note on C++11: if you don't have it, either replace `std::unique_ptr` below with `std::auto_ptr` (although it's deprecated for a reason, so careful with that), or use [boost::scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) instead.

### 1. Don't use `new`

If you need to create a (single) mountain and *don't* need to keep it alive outside the scope where it's declared, just use it as a regular variable with automatic scope:

```
void automatic_scope(int size, double seed)
{
    Mountain hill(size, Utils::powerOf2Log2(size) - 6, 0.5f, seed);
    // ... mountainous operations happen here ...
}   // hill is destroyed here - is that ok for you?
```

Similarly, if a mountain *owns* a single ChannelClass, which ought to live *exactly* as long as the mountain which owns it, just do:

```
class Mountain
{
    ChannelClass channel;

public:
    Mountain(int size, int powerthing, double something, double seed)
    : channel(size, size) // initialize other members here
    {
        // any more initialization
    }

    ChannelClass& toChannel() { return channel; }
};
```

Now the `ChannelClass` will live exactly as long as the `Mountain`, everything is destroyed automatically, and no explicit shutdown is needed.

### 2. Don't use `new[]`

Similarly, if you need several mountains with only limited scope, just use

```
void automatic_scope_vector(int size, double seed)
{
    std::vector<Mountain> hills;
    hills.push_back(Mountain(size, Utils::powerOf2Log2(size) - 6, 0.5f, seed));
    // ... mountainous operations happen here ...
}   // hills are all destroyed here
```

### 3. OK, use `new` after all

Obviously there *are* valid reasons for using new: one is mentioned already (you need to keep your mountains around longer than the block where you create them).

The other is if you need runtime polymorphism, for example if you have multiple subclasses of `Mountain` or `ChannelClass`, but you want to deal in the base classes.

We can illustrate both with a polymorphic factory function:

```
class Molehill: public Mountain { ... };
class Volcano: public Mountain { ... };

std::unique_ptr<Mountain> make_mountain(int size, double seed, bool is_molehill)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Mountain> result;
    if (is_molehill)
        result.reset(new Molehill(size, size/2, 0.01f, seed));
    else
        result.reset(new Volcano(size, size*2, 0.5f, seed));
    return result;
}

void automatic_scope_polymorphic(int size, double seed, bool is_molehill)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Mountain> hill = make_mountain(size, seed, is_molehill);
    // ... polymorphic mountainous operations happen here ...
}   // hill is destroyed here unless we gave the unique_ptr to someone else
```

Similarly, if the mountain's `ChannelClass` *needs* to be created dynamically, store *that* in a `unique_ptr`.

It may also sometimes be helpful where you'd otherwise need to copy objects to pass them around, copying is very expensive, and you can't rely on (or don't yet have) RVO or move semantics. This one's an optimisation though, so don't worry about it unless profiling shows it's a problem.

---

### Philosophy

These C++ idioms are all based on *deterministic destruction*, and the goal is to avoid writing explicit cleanup code *at all*.

Delegating memory management to containers (like `std::vector`) and smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr`) avoids the memory leaks that Java tackles with garbage collection. However, it generalises powerfully to [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) where similar automatically-scoped guard objects can automate management of *all* resources, not just memory. For example, `std::lock_guard` makes sure mutex locks are correctly released even if a function has multiple return paths, may throw exceptions, etc.

If you *do* need to write explicit cleanup code: don't write custom shut-down methods you have to call, just put it in the *destructor*. If possible, push this into low-level guard objects too.

Comment: Thanks alot! I think i might come to a solution with all those examples.

Comment: Just wanted to write, that was a great answer, +1

Comment: This is a good answer and with c++14 you might want to add std::make_unique.